# threading and multithreading in python with an example

Tags: python, multithreading

I am a beginner in python and unable to get an idea about threading.By using simple example could someone please explain threading and multithreading in python?

-Thanks

Comment: This is extremely broad. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python

Comment: You can check out tutorials about that https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Alex Martelli's answer about multithreading, as linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python).

He uses a simple program that tries some URLs then returns the contents of first one to respond.

```
import Queue
import threading
import urllib2

# called by each thread
def get_url(q, url):
    q.put(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

theurls = ["http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com"]

q = Queue.Queue()

for u in theurls:
    t = threading.Thread(target=get_url, args = (q,u))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

s = q.get()
print s
```

> This is a case where threading is used as a simple optimization: each subthread is waiting for a URL to resolve and respond, in order to put its contents on the queue; each thread is a daemon (won't keep the process up if main thread ends -- that's more common than not); the main thread starts all subthreads, does a get on the queue to wait until one of them has done a put, then emits the results and terminates (which takes down any subthreads that might still be running, since they're daemon threads).
>
> Proper use of threads in Python is invariably connected to I/O operations (since CPython doesn't use multiple cores to run CPU-bound tasks anyway, the only reason for threading is not blocking the process while there's a wait for some I/O). Queues are almost invariably the best way to farm out work to threads and/or collect the work's results, by the way, and they're intrinsically threadsafe so they save you from worrying about locks, conditions, events, semaphores, and other inter-thread coordination/communication concepts.